# 2002 Toyota Camry LE trunk lid will not open

Tags: toyota, camry, trunk

We've got a 2002 Toyota Camry LE, the trunk won't open. We've tried the key fob button, the release in the front of the car by the driver side seat, the Emergency pull handle inside the trunk itself and still nothing. Also the key has been tried in the lock on the trunk lid, turning it to the right only bends the key, rather then actually turning to unlock the trunk. Now turning it to the left is for the valet lock, because it has no button in the glove box due to it being an older model, therefore the valet lock isn't the problem. We have tried all the options, except climbing into the trunk, taking off the liner from the inside and accessing the latch. Now once we get said liner off, do we unbolt the latch piece from the trunk lid or is there another way to unlock the latch without disassembling it?

Comment: Nice first question! :)

Comment: Since the key isn't turning in the trunk lock, you can try lubricating the lock cylinder with a silicon spray lubricant. My guess is something else is bound up inside the lid, but this is a quick and easy first step. Also, is it possible that it's unlocking but the weatherproofing strips are stuck to the lid? If that were the case you should be able to get it to lift slightly. My wife's trunk will do that occasionally if it hasn't been opened in a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably won't be able to unbolt the latch. But there will be a lever that the release cable connects to as well as a lever that the lock actuator connects to. You're probably going to have to use a flat head screw driver (maybe a hammer) and unjam the lock lever.

Comment: Darn, was hoping i would be able to unbolt the latch, as I was able to in my 97 Nissan Altima, course that was 5 years older then the current problem car. I'll have to give that a go in the morning. Thanks!

Comment: While your in there, have someone pull the lever by the drivers seat, to help get an idea of what needs to happen.

Comment: @rpmerf on this gen Camry there is a little pull tab in the trunk that achieves the same thing.